# How to debug wso2 api manager code in idea

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I am trying to run API Manager 4.0.0 from source code, I download product-am and carbon-apimgt from github. How can i debug source code in idea or eclipse ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to build the product. Follow these steps in order to build the product locally.

1. Make sure you have installed Java and Maven in your machine.
2. Download or clone `carbon-apimgt` repository from
   https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt.
3. Go to `carbon-apimgt` directory and run `mvn clean install` command in the terminal. (You can ignore unit tests by running `mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true`)
4. Copy the build version to the clipboard (ex:- 9.12.3-SNAPSHOT)
5. Download or clone `product-apim` from https://github.com/wso2/product-apim
6. Replace the value of `carbon.apimgt.version` in pom.xml file with the value you copied. (ex:- `<carbon.apimgt.version>9.12.3-SNAPSHOT</carbon.apimgt.version>`)
7. Go to `product-apim` directory and run `mvn clean install` command in the terminal. (You can ignore integration tests by running `mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true` which will save your time)
8. The built pack can be found in `product-apim/modules/distribution/product/target` directory.

After building the pack, extract the content in the zip file and run `sh bin/api-manager.sh --debug 5005` command.

I recommend JetBrains Intellij IDEA to debug the code easily. So, open the `carbon-apimgt` project in IDEA. Then Add Configuration > Add new... > Remote JVM Debug > OK. After adding the configuration, you can click on the debug button and start debugging.